# Pass URL from Push Notification to WebView

Tags: java, android

I realize that issues similar to this have been addressed elsewhere. However, this is my very first project using Java and I have been unable to make this work.

My Android app features a WebView. When the app is opened during normal use, a static URL (mydomain.com) is opened. However, I will occasionally send push notifications via OneSignal that contain a different link. I want those to also be opened within the WebView.

Pursuant to the advice I've found here on SO, I am sending the custom URL via the "additional data" feature in OneSignal.

Here's what I've written so far. How can I make the `launchURL` variable accessible to the `webView.loadURL()` command? Right now, I'm receiving an error on that line: "cannot resolve symbol."

I should note that the value of launchURL is indeed showing up in my log, so the data is in fact being received and processed. I just need to make it available to webView.loadURL().

Again, please forgive my obvious ignorance here. I'm mostly a PHP guy, so this is a new frontier to me.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

            public String launchURL;

            @Override
            public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
                OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
                JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;


                if (data != null) {
                    launchURL = data.optString("launchURL");
                    if (launchURL != null) {
                        Log.i("OneSignalExample", "launchURL value: " + launchURL);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();

        if(isNetworkStatusAvailable (getApplicationContext())) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);               
            webView.loadUrl(launchURL);

         ...
```

Comment: Could you please add a log to check url value before ` webView.loadUrl(launchURL);` line?

Comment: As a step 2, lets init known url as a string there `webView.loadUrl("http://moodmusic.today");`

Comment: @Vasif I tried that, but the compiler fails when producing the app. I receive this message: `cannot find symbol variable launchURL`

Comment: @Vasif Yes, when I use a string as a URL everything works correctly.

Comment: You mean when u add log before "webView.loadUrl(launchURL);" you get err?

Comment: Yes, the variable name is not recognized and produces the "cannot find symbol" error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `public String launchURL;` out of class, right after `protected void onCreate....` part

Or just move webview loading to your notification listener where you set `launchURL`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this as shown below. Apparently the `ExampleNotificationOpenedHander` prefix was necessary.

```
   if (ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL == null){
                webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
            }else{
                webView.loadUrl(ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.launchURL);
            }
```